# Drawing an image loaded from other files (love2d)

Tags: graphics, love2d

So I have a "load_assets.lua" file inside my game folder along with the "main.lua". Inside the "load_assets.lua" file I have a "love.graphics.newImage(image)"
and in the "main.lua" file I have the "love.graphics.draw(image)".

I've tried to create this function inside the "main.lua" file:

```
function love.draw(i)
    love.graphics.draw(i)
end
```

and this function inside the "load_assets.lua" file:

```
image = love.graphics.newImage(image)
lovedraw(image)
```

but it still doesn't seem to work.

Of course, the code is a little more complex than this, but similar:

```
--in "main.lua" the function is actually:

function title(lvl0)
    love.graphics.draw(lvl0)
end

--and in "load_assets" it's:

function love.load()
    lvl0 = love.graphics.newImage("lvl0.png")
end

title(lvl0)
```

When I run the code I get this error:

```
Error

title.lua:3: bad argument #1 to 'draw' (Drawable expected, got nil)


Traceback

[C]: in function 'draw'
title.lua:3: in function 'title'
main.lua:16: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

Comment: Questions about `title(lv10)` - is it inside of another function and are you calling it from `main.lua`?

Comment: Yes, it is in a separate function. Want me to share the whole game folder?

Comment: @TudoSzabo Hopefully my answer helps; if I misunderstood anything please share the relevant code so I can try and find a more specific answer!

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not proper to add SOLVED to the question title. If an answer you received here provided a solution, you can mark the question solved by checking the mark next to that answer to accept it. If you found the solution yourself and want to share it, write an answer in the space below to do so; see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the specifics of your code, but the following worked for me:

***load_assets.lua***

```
function love.load()
    lv10 = love.graphics.newImage("image.png")
end
```

***main.lua***

```
require("load_assets")

function title(lv10)
    love.graphics.draw(lv10)
end

function love.draw()
    title(lv10)
end
```

`Love2d` has several built in functions that you can override to create your program. Ideally, all your function calls happen from within these programs.

So, in ***load_assets.lua*** I override the `love.load()` function to create `lv10`. By default `love.load()` is called [exactly once, at the start of the program](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.load).

In ***main.lua*** I define the `title()` function, then override `love.draw()` to call `title()`. By default, `love.draw()` is called [every update cycle of the love engine](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.draw) (every frame).

Comment: @TudorSzabo if this works can you please check the answer box! Thanks :D